# Accessibility on UIStepper

Tags: ios, uikit, voiceover

I know that voiceover can a be  bag of hurt when used with an UIStepper because the UIButtons that it contains can't be customised. However I use this control to change a value displayed on a label:[image: UIStepper under the labels that they change]

I don't want to insert a new control just for voiceover and subclassing a control like UIStepper doesn't seem a good solution. Any ideas to implement voiceover with this interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a view which wraps your label(s) and stepper together and which deals with the accessibility. So, the subviews are all disabled for accessibility and the wrapper view presents the text in the labels, the current value of the stepper and provides / handles a swipe based interface to increment and decrement the stepper. So, overall, the wrapper view would work like a slider.

Comment: Can you detail how to implement the swipes with voiceover?

Comment: you need to look at `UIAccessibilityTraitAdjustable` and implement the increment and decrement methods it specifies

Answer (score 1):

An interface implementing a stepper may be well vocalized and presented by VoiceOver using the `adjustable values`.

A complete explanation is detailed [here](https://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/en/mobile/ios/development/#continuous-adjustable-values) including illustrations and code snippets (ObjC + swift).